# Encrypting PHP page

Tags: php, encryption

I have a basic PHP page that uses user input from a HTML page to generate a list for the user.

How do I encrypt this page to prevent users from accessing the source code?

I have seen a lot of information around the web regarding padding html, disabling right click and using Javascript to encrypt code. I could not get Javascript encoding to work, and I didn't feel confident using one of the 'specialized' services, so I came here looking for further answers.

After all that research, it turns out PHP code is not seen by the user like HTML code is able to be seen. As HTML was visible to users, I assumed the PHP code on my PHP file would be visible too. The result is a relief, because it means my PHP code is protected from the public eye.

After a short query and some helpful answers below I have found a very simple solution to what seemed like a difficult question.

I hope this post helps people in the same situation who feel like they are unable to protect their code, so that can find relief in what is really a very simple solution.

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: PHP code is not viewable to users.

Comment: Your php code will be interpreted on the server, and the source code will not be accessible to the end user, unless there is a server misconfiguration.

Comment: browser> view source. do you see any php code?

Comment: If you want to hide the html page, you have to move it outside the public folder or configure the server to not allow it to be downloaded.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As stated by others, php code is not accessible to the public, unless your server is wrongly configured or hacked in some way.

However, the form data is sent between the client and server unencrypted. For sensitive data(e.g. Passwords), this has security problems. To solve this you need to buy an SSL certificate. Most hosting companies can sell you this.

Bear in mind the final output source of HTML, CSS and JavaScript will always be visible of the user, due to the way the web works. For many people, this openness is what makes the Internet so great.

Answer (score 1):

You can encode your code with ionCube Encoder.